# Excel says no "End Sub", and crashes just by moving cursor

Tags: excel, crash, vba

I am writing a VBA code to go through a specified range or ranges, look for a keyword provided by the user at run-time, and grab the value in the cell offset from the cell with the keyword by an amount also provided by the user. For instance, if you wanted to look through A1:B10 for the word "Apple" and then grab the value in the cell to the right of every instance of "Apple", it can do that. Two weird things have been occurring for me. First and not so weird, when I run it and click the cancel button on the userform that only contains the single line "Unload Me", it throws an error saying it expected and End Sub statement, but it has one. I don't know why it is doing that. Weird thing number 2. Whenever I click and move the cursor to the end of the file after the Cancel_Click() sub, my excel crashes and closes. Every. Single. Time. And it is weird that it does that just from me clicking. It also sometimes happens when I click around the Cancel_Click() sub or hit enter around there too. Just simply from clicking. I don't get it. Any ideas? Code contained in the userform is below. Fyi, the user can input ranges like "A1:A10,E1:E10" separated by commas for multiple ranges. I don't think it is important for this question, but I thought I would add that since i don't know how to add the userform here, if you even can.

```
Private Sub Accept_Click()
'Searches for string input into the KeywordBox
'Grabs contents of the cell defined by the OffsetBox
'The range it searches through is defined by the RangeBox

Dim rawRange As String: rawRange = Me.RangeBox.Text
Dim rawOffset As String: rawOffset = Me.OffsetBox.Text
Dim Keyword As String: Keyword = Me.KeywordBox.Text
Dim numOfRanges As Integer: numOfRanges = 1
Dim Ranges() As Range
Dim commaLoc As Integer: commaLoc = -1
Dim tempRange As String: tempRange = rawRange
Dim offset As Integer
Dim values() As Double
Dim valCount As Integer: valCount = 0

'--------------------------------------------------------
'Set ranges

For i = 1 To Len(rawRange)
    If (Mid(rawRange, i, 1) = ",") Then
        numOfRanges = numOfRanges + 1
    End If
Next

ReDim Ranges(numOfRanges) As Range

If (Not numOfRanges = 1) Then
    For i = 1 To numOfRanges - 1
        commaLoc = InStr(1, tempRange, ",")
        Set Ranges(i) = Range(Left(tempRange, commaLoc - 1))
        tempRange = Right(tempRange, Len(tempRange) - commaLoc)
    Next
End If

Set Ranges(numOfRanges) = Range(tempRange)
'---------------------------------------------------------
'Set offset

If (IsNumeric(rawOffset)) Then
    offset = CInt(rawOffset)
Else:
    MsgBox ("Offset was not input as a number")
    Exit Sub
End If
'----------------------------------------------------------
'Searches for keyword

For i = 1 To numOfRanges
    For Each cell In Ranges(i)
        If (cell.Value = Keyword) Then
            valCount = valCount + 1
        End If
    Next
Next

ReDim values(valCount) As Double
valCount = 0

For i = 1 To numOfRanges
    For Each cell In Ranges(i)
        If (cell.Value = Keyword) Then
            valCount = valCount + 1
            values(valCount) = cell.offset(0, offset).Value
        End If
    Next
Next

For i = 1 To valCount
    Range("I" & i).Value = values(i)
Next

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: You have `Else:` but you just should have `Else` - potential confusion there....

Comment: I tested that in a basic sub and it still functions as intended. It doesn't seem to make a difference. It is unnecessary though. I was brainwashed by Python. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had similar, weird things happen to me. A good thing to try is to force the VBA project to reset, then save, exit, and restart Excel.

To force a project reset, add an Enum to the general section of one of your code modules. It doesn't matter what the enum is...make it something simple, like

```
Enum stoplight
    Red
    Yellow
    Green
End Enum
```

As you do that, you'll get a message saying that it will reset your project. That's fine; let that happen. Then save your Excel workbook, exit excel completely, start it up again, reload your workbook, go into the VBA Editor, and delete the enum you added. Then recompile and see if things work better for you.

Comment: I was able to fix it in a sort of similar manner. I made a new workbook and just copied everything over there, code and all, and it worked. I think what you suggested may have worked. I did try exiting and reopening excel and that did not work before, though. But never added an Enum like that. Thanks though!

Comment: I learned the Enum trick fairly recently. Prior to that, I did what you did: copy everything to a new workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You put an "Exit Sub" in the set offset, this is probably causing your problem.

Comment: The "Exit Sub" only gets called if the input in the userform is not a number, and I made sure that it wasn't several times. The MsgBox would also appear if that got called, and it didn't. So that shouldn't be it. Definitely not bad to check it though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by making a new workbook and copying everything over. It worked fine. I think the original was corrupted somehow. For those having the same issue, I think Rich Holton's answer would be worth a try in case you have more than just a few things to copy. Thanks everyone for you time and input on this!